# Migration to other sites when off-topic?

Tags: feature-request, migration, flagging

If I flag a question as being off-topic, and then say that it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network, I am then presented with a list of sites that it might be appropriate for. The problem is, the only one in the list is meta.DSP.SE. Is it possible to make other sites available in this list? I can think of a couple that might come up reasonably often:

- electronics.SE
- math.SE

There may be more.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, we [discourage migration](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/) unless a question simply makes no sense on the site that it's asked on.  This is especially important on beta sites which are still establishing themselves.  If someone has found their way to Digital Signal Processing and asked a question, it's generally best to assume that this is the right spot for them to ask unless it's overwhelmingly obvious they are in [the wrong place](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/the-pee-wee-herman-rule/).

Moderators *are* able to migrate questions, so if you strongly feel a question belongs on another site, you could flag it "other" and leave a note for a moderator.  But generally, it's best to just vote to close and leave a comment explaining the problem.  That way the asker can decide.

See also: [What is the reasoning behind restricting the number of migration paths?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203318/1438)